# Validate User Input of 11 digit Mobile number into 4 - 3 - 4 pattern using a javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Can anyone help me how to make User Input of 11 digit Mobile number into 4 - 3 - 4 pattern using a javascript and i dont know how to start. By the way im new with javascripting. it would be nice to if you could help me :)

Comment: There are a lot of answers for the same question already. :)

Comment: do you have a link sir? :)

Comment: Look at the related section in the sidebar. There are a ton of links there.

Answer (score 4):

Use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method with capturing group regex.

```js
console.log(
  '12345678910'.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3')
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtMob').attr({ maxLength: 13 });
        $("#txtMob").on('keyup', function () {
            var value = $("#txtMob").val();
            if ($("#txtMob").val().length == 4 || $("#txtMob").val().length == 8) {
                $("#txtMob").val($("#txtMob").val() + "-");
            }

        })
    })
```

Comment: This won't work if the user tries to edit an existing value.